# Web View menu displaying at wrong time

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, android-menu, android-inflate

I have a webview created and working fine. The Menu displays but not when the web view is running. I think i need to nest the OnCreateOptionsMenu() function inside the other function that creates the web view. Does that make sence? Am i Correct? How would i do that?

It displays my menu when the menu button is pushed and the web view is not displayed.
When the web view is displayed and menu button is pushed it displays androids defaut menu.

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Activity mActivity = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // SETS DEFAULT MODE TO LANDSCAPE
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        // Makes Progress bar Visible
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,
            Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://Google.com");

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            mActivity.setTitle("Google.com");
            mActivity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            }

        });

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
       return true;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to have your own onKeyDown event handler, and intercept the Menu button there. Otherwise it gets consumed by the webview. I am just guessing though.